# How can I move an email message from one folder to another using PHP imap

Tags: php, imap, imap-open

I am trying to read messages from an email... Depending on the subject's content I want to move it to either a "Processes" or "unauthorized" folder

save the messages in an array and then move the message from the INBOX to the Proceeded folder

Here is what I have done

```
// Checks the inbox
if ($messages = imap_search($this->conn,'ALL'))
{
    // Sorts the messages newest first
    rsort($messages);
    // Loops through the messages
    foreach ($messages as $id)
    {
        $header = imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $id);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($this->conn, $id, 1);

        if(    !isset($header->from[0]->mailbox) || empty($header->from[0]->mailbox)
            || !isset($header->from[0]->host) || empty($header->from[0]->host)
            || !isset($header->subject) || empty($header->from[0]->host)
        ) {
            continue;
        }

        $from = $header->from[0]->mailbox . '@' . $header->from[0]->host;
        $subject = $header->subject;    

        $outlook = $this->_parseReplyExchange($message);

        if($outlook !== false){
            $newReply = $outlook;
        } else {
            $newReply = $this->_parseReplySystem($message);
        }

        $ticketID = $this->_parseTicketID($subject);
        if($ticketID !== false){
            $f = array();
            $f['id'] = $id;
            $f['from'] = $from;
            $f['subject'] = $subject;
            $f['ticketID'] = $ticketID;
            $f['message'] = $newReply;
            $this->replyList[] = $f;

            $imapresult = imap_mail_move($this->conn, $id, $box, CP_UID);

            if($imapresult == false){
                echo imap_last_error();
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    exit('No messages on the IMAP server.');
}
```

I read the message with no issues, but when trying to moving the message I get an error.

```
.[TRYCREATE] The requested item could not be found.
Notice: Unknown: [TRYCREATE] The requested item could not be found. (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

I think the issue is the way how I am passing the $id to the `imap_mail_move` function.

I also tried to convert the message sequance number to a UID number like so `$f['id'] = imap_uid($this->conn , $id )` and that did not work..

I also tried this

```
$imapresult = imap_mail_move($this->conn, '1:' . $id, $box);
$imapresult = imap_mail_move($this->conn, '1:' . $id, $box, CP_UID);
```

I even tried to copy and then delete the message and that did not work.

```
$imapresult = imap_mail_copy($c, '1', 'INBOX/Processed', CP_MOVE);
```

I can't get the message to move.

How can I correctly move the message?

Comment: You are mixing sequence ids and UIDs.  Why did you pass the CP_UID flag to imap_mail_move?

Comment: @Max I tried using the to convert the sequence number to the UID and that also did not work `imap_uid($this->conn , $id )`  it seems that I should be passing a range but I am not sure how should I generate the range? I want to move one message at a time as in some case messages are moved to a different folders

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.

The issue was is that the `Processed` folder was not a sub folder of the INBOX folder. It was a folder setting next to INBOX.

The take away here is when using the [imap_mail_move()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-copy.php) function you will need to pass either a sequence number or a range of sequence numbers

```
$imapresult = imap_mail_move($this->conn, $id, $box);
```

Each message received have a sequence number `1,2,3,n` where n is the newest message received in a giving box.

Here is an examples of the `$id` variable

```
1
1:5
1,2,5,6,7
```

The first example means move message 1 from current folder to a new folder defined in `$box`.

The second example means move messages 1,2,3,4,5 from current folder to a new folder defined in `$box`.

The third example means move messages 1,2,5,6,7 from current folder to a new folder defined in `$box`.

In addition, here are some examples of the $box variable

```
'INBOX/Processed'
'Unauthorized'
```

The first example means the `Processed` folder that is located under the INBOX folder.

The second example means the `Unauthorized` folder that is located next "same location" to the INBOX folder

To know where each folder is located in your email, you can use [imap_list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-list.php) function.

I hope this helps other as it took me a while to find this silly issue.